# Parsing and chopping a long string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I've searched but didn't quite find something for my case.  Basically, I'm trying to split the following line:

```
(CU!DIVD:WEXP:DIVD-:DIVD+:RWEXP:RDIVD:RECL:RLOSS:MISCDI:WEXP-:INT:RGAIN:DIVOP:RRGAIN:DIVOP-:RDIVOP:RRECL:RBRECL:INT -:RRLOSS:INT +:RINT:RDIVD-:RECL-:RWXPOR:WEXPOR:MISCRE:WEXP+:RWEXP-:RBWEXP:RECL+:RRECL-:RBDIVD)
```

You can read this as CU is NOT DIVD or WEXP or DIV- or and so on.  What I'd like to do is split this line if it's over 65 characters into something more manageable like this:

```
(CU!DIVD:WEXP:DIVD-:DIVD+:RWEXP:RDIVD:RECL:RLOSS:MISCDI:WEXP-)
(CU!INT:RGAIN:DIVOP:RRGAIN:DIVOP-:RDIVOP:RRECL:RBRECL:INT-)
(CU!RRLOSS:INT +:RINT:RDIVD-:RECL-:RWXPOR:WEXPOR:MISCRE:WEXP+)
(CU!RWEXP-:RBWEXP:RECL+:RRECL-:RBDIVD)
```

They're all less than 65 characters.  This can be stored in a list and I can take care of the rest.  I'm starting to work on this with RegEx but I'm having a bit of trouble.

Additionally, it can also have the following conditionals:

- !
- <
- >
- =
- !=
- !<
- !>

As of now, I have this:

```
def FilterParser(iteratorIn, headerIn):
    listOfStrings = []
    for eachItem in iteratorIn:
        if len(str(eachItem.text)) > 65:
             exmlLogger.error('The length of filter' + eachItem.text + ' exceeds the limit and will be dropped')
             pass
        else:
            listOfStrings.append(rightSpaceFill(headerIn + EXUTIL.intToString(eachItem),80))
return ''.join(stringArray)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using regex, edited to include the `CU!` prefix (or any other prefix) to the beginning of each new line:

```
import re
s = '(CU!DIVD:WEXP:DIVD-:DIVD+:RWEXP:RDIVD:RECL:RLOSS:MISCDI:WEXP-:INT:RGAIN:DIVOP:RRGAIN:DIVOP-:RDIVOP:RRECL:RBRECL:INT -:RRLOSS:INT +:RINT:RDIVD-:RECL-:RWXPOR:WEXPOR:MISCRE:WEXP+:RWEXP-:RBWEXP:RECL+:RRECL-:RBDIVD)'

prefix = '(' + re.search(r'\w+(!?[=<>]|!)', s).group(0)
maxlen = 64 - len(prefix)  # max line length of 65, prefix and ')' will be added
regex = re.compile(r'(.{1,%d})(?:$|:)' % maxlen)
lines = [prefix + line + ')' for line in regex.findall(s[len(prefix):-1])]

>>> print '\n'.join(lines)
(CU!DIVD:WEXP:DIVD-:DIVD+:RWEXP:RDIVD:RECL:RLOSS:MISCDI:WEXP-)
(CU!INT:RGAIN:DIVOP:RRGAIN:DIVOP-:RDIVOP:RRECL:RBRECL:INT -)
(CU!RRLOSS:INT +:RINT:RDIVD-:RECL-:RWXPOR:WEXPOR:MISCRE:WEXP+)
(CU!RWEXP-:RBWEXP:RECL+:RRECL-:RBDIVD)
```

First we need to grab the prefix, we do this using `re.search().group(0)`, which returns the entire match.  Each of the final lines should be at most 65 characters, the regex that we will use to get these lines will not include the prefix or the closing parentheses, which is why `maxlen` is `64 - len(prefix)`.

Now that we know the most characters we can match, the first part of the regex `(.{1,<maxlen>)` will match at most that many characters.  The portion at the end, `(?:$|:)`, is used to make sure that we only split the string on semi-colons or at the end of the string.  Since there is only one capturing group `regex.findall()` will return only that match, leaving off the trailing semi-colon.  Here is what it looks like for you sample string:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(regex.findall(s[len(prefix):-1]))
['DIVD:WEXP:DIVD-:DIVD+:RWEXP:RDIVD:RECL:RLOSS:MISCDI:WEXP-',
 'INT:RGAIN:DIVOP:RRGAIN:DIVOP-:RDIVOP:RRECL:RBRECL:INT -',
 'RRLOSS:INT +:RINT:RDIVD-:RECL-:RWXPOR:WEXPOR:MISCRE:WEXP+',
 'RWEXP-:RBWEXP:RECL+:RRECL-:RBDIVD']
```

The list comprehension is used to construct a list of all of the lines by adding the prefix and the trailing `)` to each result.  The slicing of `s` is done so that the prefix and the trailing `)` are stripped off of the original string before `regex.findall()`.  Hope this helps!

Comment: That's a great start!  How would I 'elegantly' strip the CU! (or for that matter any alphanumerical and the accompanying conditional) and append it to each of the new lines?

Comment: @mastashake57 - Sorry, looks like I missed that element of your question, working on an edit now.

Comment: Thanks, F.J., you're helping me out.  BTW, totally appreciate the breakdown.

Comment: @mastashake57 - Okay, check out my modified answer, it should now be doing what you want.

Comment: It's great how regex allowed this code to be so concise. I just hope your tags don't exceed `maxlen` or they will be broken across lines.

Comment: Brilliant!  I'm putting it through my initial testing and the results are perfect.  Question, what if I wanted to split on ~ (the tilda)?  Our proprietary parsing engine considers : and ~ as conditional "OR".

Comment: @mastashake57 - Change the second part of the compiled regex from `(?:$|:)` to `(?:$|[:~])`.